# Table created in PostgresSql is not visible in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I run the following query in Postgres:

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema'
```

The query returns 14 tables

I run the following code in Python:

```
    #print the tables in the db<br>
    cur = conn.cursor()<br>
    sql = """SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema'""";<br>
    cur.execute(sql)<br>
    tablelist=[]<br>
    for (tablename) in cur:
        tablelist.append(tablename)<br>
    cur.close()<br>
    conn.close()<br>
```

This code returns 13 tables

Why is there a difference in the count of tables?

Comment: well, for sure you are connecting to different databases .make sure you are connecting to the same database

Comment: What is the name of the extra table in the first query?

Comment: Some background. I had created a new table in Postgres. But I couldn't access it in Python. Python kept saying something to the effect the new table did not exist. As a result I did the above check, i.e. sql query to code check of tablelisting. After 2 hours of being frustrated, I shutdown down PgAdmin. Took a break. Opened up PgAdmin and discovered my new table no longer existed. Recreated the new table and now it is accessible in Python.